# Show notification when battery level is low

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to see a notification when the battery level is below 20% so I wrote this code.

In another Activity i use CheckBattery check = new CheckBattery(); to call the class but doesn't work because i don't see the notification. Why? How can i fix?

Comment: have you given permission in manifest

Comment: for battery stats and have you declared your receiver in manifest for broadcast reciever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you forgot to declare [BATTERY_STATS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BATTERY_STATS) permission in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Disclaimer: I just wrote up this answer not having seen Suhail suggest the same thing in the comments section for the original question.